# How to detect if one element touched another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create an online webapp game like Mario.

I have an image of a portal, and a picture of Mario. 
I know how to move the position of the image of mario with the arrow keys. 
What I don't know is how to respond to the event when the picture of Mario touches the portal? The images have ids of "mario" and "portal". 
Should I use jQuery to solve this question. 
Thanks in advance!-

Comment: You might want to look up "Game loop" and "Colision maps". One simple approach is to evaluate if the position of Mario is the same as the door, on every iteration of the game loop. And this evaluation may be done with every object. Of course, for more complex games the approach is different

Comment: I recommend checking out [Phaser](http://www.phaser.io) and using their arcade physics. You will need an engine like that to accomplish your goal. Mozilla offers a game engine comparison guide to point you in the right direction [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Tools/Engines_and_tools)

Comment: Thank you! I am trying out Phaser right now!